# Tar files in groups by total size

Tags: tar, zip, gzip, archive

I need to tar (and gzip) a long list of files but I need to do that in groups based on each group size.

For example assume I have a list of 100 files, 1Mb each and I want to create archives that are not larger than 10Mb. As a result I want to get 10 archived files.

Note that each archived file needs to be readable and extractable independently of the others.

Comment: You've not really asked a question here.  This appears to be more of a programming query asking "please write me a script to do...".  You should try to be specific about what it is that you're stuck on.

Comment: Maybe reading this thread will be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/290986/how-to-create-tar-archive-split-into-or-spanning-multiple-files

Comment: @margin thanks for the link! I was looking into that myself but the problem with `--multi-volume` is that it does not support zipping the contents, only packaging.